# How to add a subcollection to firestore on c#?

Tags: c#, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to add a subcollection to a document on c# on firestore, I can not find it in the documentation page for firestore?

I am new to firestore and nosql and a lot of these stuff are still complicated for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just create a document in the subcollection - the collection itself isn't an entity you need to create.

So if you already have a `DocumentReference` for something, you can use:

```
DocumentReference topDoc = ...;
CollectionReference subCollection = topDoc.Collection("subcollection");
DocumentReference subDoc = await subCollection.AddAsync(new { Name = "Jon", Score = 10 });
```

Or if you want to specify an ID, create a new `DocumentReference` and then create the document from that:

```
DocumentReference topDoc = ...;
CollectionReference subCollection = topDoc.Collection("subcollection");
DocumentReference subDoc = subCollection.Document("subdoc");
await subDoc.CreateAsync(new { Name = "Jon", Score = 10 });
```

Comment: hey man thanks alot. I just realized that.  I ended  up doing this ......

Comment: thanks alot man. I was able to create a subcollection based off that. lol. I also just realized this might cost alot so i might have to switch my subcollections to like an array of objects in my original thanks!!!

Comment: @erejotA: I'm not quite sure I follow you, but `CollectionReference.Document` and `DocumentReference.Collection` don't cost anything themselves - they don't make a call to the server at all.